# Wheels changing on Giant Rebel 4

Tags: wheels

Very often even without extreme riding my wheels are getting light 8-like form.
Is this the reason to change wheels or sleeve
Its more cosmetic problem which can evolute to more problems

My bike is Giant Rebel 4

Comment: Welcome to bicycles.SX. In it's current form your question is very likely to be closed as it does not get quite clear what exactly you are asking for. Could you please provide us with some more information? What riding do you do that you call "not extreme"? Are the wheels only slightly out of true or bent so much that they don't turn anymore? Please also have a look at our [tour](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to get an idea about how good questions and answers in our Format should look like.

Comment: Rebel or Revel?

Comment: What does "light 8-like form" mean?  Are you talking about the tires (rubber part) or the wheels (metal part)?

Comment: its like this but not so hard :) 
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_RmNSmzFoAmo/SF6ZXEOdE0I/AAAAAAAAAMk/58fm2WKb-Uo/s1600/IMG_0076.JPG

Comment: As @BenediktBauer mentions, your question is a bit unclear. I think this is partially due to formatting issues and partially due to terminology issues. We have a [Terminology Indes](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index) if you need help with terminology. It would also be helpful to edit your question to use complete sentences and proper punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

What is going on with your wheels is known as being *out of true*, or in its extreme form (like the photo that you provided), *taco-ed*. This is not all that uncommon on entry level bikes like the Giant you have.

This can be caused by several different things - the most common is just general wear on the wheel. Over time, small changes in pressure on the spokes cause the tension around the wheel to become uneven, which causes the rim to warp. Other causes include poor construction of the wheel, cheap parts, or abuse.

If you have fixed your wheel several times, and it still happens, then it is likely a defect - I would take it to the shop you bought it from and ask to see if they can look into a warranty for you. I don't know Giant's warranty policy off the top of my head, but I have worked at a shop that sold Giants, and IIRC, they were generally accepting of defective stuff. Some bike shops will do everything in their power to not take in your wheel and attempt to get a warranty for it, but if you persist long enough, they will probably make a phone call or two.